# SceneKit - View that depends on width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I have maybe a weird question.
My scene:

- A cube
- A camera (same y, z position and looking to zero)

Currently and Wish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0L7D.png

I launched the scene on iPhone Plus and iPad Pro. Now I am thinking the view/presentation on the app depends on the height of the device and the iPad adds some space at the left/ right side (Look at the image Nr.1).

But I want that the view/presentation will depend on the width of the device and that the iPad will remove some space at the top/bottom (Look at the the image Nr. 2).

I hope you can understand and help me!

Comment: Set Leading,trailing,botom,top constraint.Don't fix height,width constraints.

Comment: @Shivam Tripathi - Thank you, but what did you mean exactly?

Comment: If u could create leading & trailing constraint with 17% of width(e.g for iphone - 17*320/100). Your cube will appear as u are expecting.